# Make git submodule independently usable from superproject

Tags: git, docker, git-submodules

I have a larger superproject with submodules, some submodules are supposed to build docker images, which I'd like to build independently from superproject. The problem is that git operations are failing within the docker build process because docker cuts the docker context on the level of subproject:

`fatal: Not a git repository: ../.git/modules/<submodule>`

The issue is basically that `<submodule>/.git` is available within the docker context, but `<superproject>/.git` is not. Hence, I need a submodule without reference to the superproject.
Now I'm looking for some sort of git-dir splitting mechanism for submodules. Basically the reverse of [git-submodule-absorbgitdirs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#git-submodule-absorbgitdirs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submodule's `.git` file is in the form of `gitdir: ...` which points to the actual `.git` dir of your submodule.

You can copy the submodule's "real" `.git` dir into your Docker image before building it, and replace the `.git` file with that dir when building the Docker image.
This is *almost* enough - you also need to fix the config worktree and nested submodules.

---

Here are the steps in detail:

Before building the Docker image, copy the real `.git` directory of your submodule next to your Dockerfile so you could copy it in the Dockerfile:

```bash
DOTGIT=$(cat $SUBMODULE/.git)
GITDIR=${DOTGIT/gitdir: }
cp -rf $SUBMODULE/$GITDIR $SUBMODULE.gitdir
```

Then remove `worktree` from the submodule's `config`:

```bash
sed -i '/worktree =/d' $SUBMODULE.gitdir/config
```

Then in your Dockerfile, copy the submodule

```
COPY $SUBMODULE /submodule
WORKDIR /submodule
```

Delete the original .git file

```
RUN rm .git
```

And copy the original subdmoule's `.git` directory instead of it:

```
COPY ./$SUBMODULE.gitdir .git
```

If you have nested submodules, you can fix them with absorbgitdirs

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
RUN git submodule absorbgitdirs
```

Comment: It generally works. Thank you very much. One probably needs to copy the git dir into the submodule in order to use `docker build .` from within the repo. The assumption is that the submodule has its defined way to build so `RUN rm .git` is not something it would usually do. That can be done from the outside though.

Comment: @gnod Indeed the git dir is copied into the submodule in `COPY ./$SUBMODULE.gitdir .git` which in turn was created by a script before docker build . In this case, `RUN rm .git` only deletes the **pointer** to the git dir which is inaccessible to the docker build (its contents is `gitdir: ... `).